# Cardinality of a Set (Adding Coins)

Tags: combinatorics

Here $\mathbb{N}=\{ 0, 1, 2, 3, \dots\}$.

> What is the cardinality of the set below?

$\{(N, D, Q) \mid \text{$0.05N+0.1D+0.25Q=3$ and $N,D, Q\in \mathbb N$}\}$

---

To figure this answer, we need to determine the coefficient of $C_{60}x^{60}$ in the expression $(\sum_{i=0}^{60}x^i)(\sum_{i=0}^{30}x^{2i})(\sum_{i=0}^{12}x^{5i})$.

This converges as follows:$(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^i)(\sum_{i=0}^{{\infty}}x^{2i})(\sum_{i=0}^{{\infty}}x^{{5i}})=\frac{1}{1-x}\cdot \frac{1}{1-x^2}\cdot \frac{1}{1-x^5}$.

Thus, the Cauchy inner product is between the first two is ... $C_{60}=\sum_{l=0}^{60}a_{l}\cdot b_{60-l}c_{something}=?$. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think this problem has something to do with the lower limit of the sum of the multinomial theorem. However, I could be wrong. I feel like there is a "trick" to solving this problem that I am missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you just want to know the number, you can search through all 19800 3-tuples $(N,D,Q) \in \mathbb N^3$ for which $0 < N \le 60$, $0 < D \le 30$, $0 < Q \le 12$.

Comment: I want to know how to do it without a computer/calculator. Thank you though. I do see where you are getting the bounds from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$0.05N+0.1 D+0.25 Q= 3$ is equivalent to $N+2 D+5 Q= 60$

And the number of triplets $(N,D,Q) \in \mathbb  N^3$ satisfying this equation is equal to the $60$-th term ($x^{60}$) of the development in power series of

$$S(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}\frac{1}{1-x^2}\frac{1}{1-x^5}.$$

You can prove that using the theory of [generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function).

Comment: Where would you go from there? I just would like to know more about this. Thank you for your response.

Comment: In fact when you make the expansion you get $S(x) = (1+x +x^2 + \dots + x^N + \dots)( 1 +x^2 +x^4+ \dots + x^{2D}+ \dots)( 1 +x^5 +x^{10}+ \dots + x^{5Q}+ \dots)$. And you can see that a solution of $N+2 D+5 Q= 60$ corresponds to one single way of picking terms in the series in order fort their product to have power $60$ and vice versa.

Comment: So, how do you determine what term the coefficient of $x^{60}$ is?

Comment: You can use [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product).

Comment: I posted some more above. Am I on the right track? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Two issues on what you added: (1) here we don't only have the product of two power series but of three. Hence you have to consider the product of the two first and then to make the product with the last one. (2) you're mixing series coefficients and the variable $x$.

Comment: To determine $C_{60}$ do you look at the infinite stuff? I guess I don't know where that part comes to play. I'm stuck here...